# Selecting a single ID by the most recent date Order Date -SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this

```
Indvdl_Store_ID     Indvdl_ID     Order_ID     Order_Date 
    101               123         A000         12/24/2011 
    101               241         B002         01/01/2013
    101               201         Y180         01/01/2016
```

Since we have the same Indvdl_Store_ID associated with 3 different Indvdl_IDs, I want to select/keep the most recent Individual ID for that Indvdl_StoreID based on the order date, but still keep all of the orders associated to the Indvdl_Store_ID. So I would like my final results to look like this

```
Indvdl_Store_ID     Indvdl_ID     Order_ID     Order_Date 
    101               201         A000         12/24/2011 
    101               201         B002         01/01/2013
    101               201         Y180         01/01/2016
```

I have tried using row_number to dedupe and then joining the final results back to the table on Indvdl_store_ID, but I still seem to be having Issues getting the correct results. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Indvdl_Store_ID, Indvdl_ID, Order_ID, Order_Date ) AS
SELECT 101, 123, 'A000', DATE '2011-12-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 101, 241, 'B002', DATE '2013-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 201, 'Y180', DATE '2016-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Indvdl_Store_ID,
       MAX( Indvdl_ID ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ORDER_DATE )
                        OVER ( PARTITION BY INDVDL_STORE_ID )
           AS Indvdl_ID,
       Order_ID,
       Order_Date
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
INDVDL_STORE_ID  INDVDL_ID ORDER_ID ORDER_DATE        
--------------- ---------- -------- -------------------
            101        201 A000     2011-12-24 00:00:00 
            101        201 Y180     2016-01-01 00:00:00 
            101        201 B002     2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be with an inner join and group by

```
select  b.Order_Date,  max(a.Indvdl_Store_ID), max( a.Indvdl_ID), b.Order_ID  
from my_table as b 
inner join my_table as a on  a.Indvdl_ID = b.Indvdl_ID
group by b.Order_Date
```